# Информация о сетевом подключении и её изменение

Tags: python, flask

Как с помощью Python и Flask получить IP адрес, MAC адрес, Subnet, DNS, geteway хоста, а потом изменить это?

Желательно использовать отдельный файл, к примеру - cfg.conf, из которого и будет браться конфигурация.

Напишите пожалуйста примерный код и ссылку на документацию.

Comment: Flask тут ни при чём, он всего лишь веб-фреймворк, а всё остальное зависит от системы

Comment: @andreymal RPi система. Но вопрос все равно остается прежним - получить IP адрес, MAC адрес, Subnet, DNS, geteway хоста а потом изменить это. Желательно использовать отдельный файл к примеру - cfg.conf из которого и будут браться конфигурация